# Pandas, groupby, creating all combinations

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have this fake data frame.

```
{ 'Name':['James','John','Carlos','Bob','Lucy','Javier','Juan','Julia','Jaime','Peter','Philip','George'],    
 'Country': ['EUA','EUA','EUA','EUA','EUA','EUA','EUA','EUA','Brazil','EUA','Brazil','EUA'],    
 'State': ['Cali','Cali','Cali','Cali','Cali','Cali','NY','NY','SP','NY','SP','NY'],    
'City':['SF','LA','SF','SF','LA','LA','NY','LB','SP','LF','SP','NY'],
'Points': [200,150,100,265,150,250,120,230,320,150,125,254]}
```

Firts, I am using the groupby function.
Then, I would like create all combinations (with no rep) into a new data frame and compare the points for each match(win draw,lose).

the final dataframe header would be something like: Name/Points/Competitor/Competidor Points/Result(WIN.draw.LOSE)
But if there are two name that start with J in the same group, they cannot compete.
So far I got this and do not know what to do next.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("testecampeonatoBRSOJA.csv", sep = ";")
grouped = df.groupby(['Country','State','City'])
print(grouped.groups)

for i in grouped:
   print(i)
```

Comment: I don't see how your sample data relates to your desired outcome.  There are no columns Competitor/Competidor

Comment: Maybe creat a new df with all combiantion with the column competitor